# Add email account to a domain I bought through AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I registered a domain using AWS Route 53. Let's say that it's mydomain.com. 
I want to use SES as an email solution for my app because it's already hosted in AWS anyways.

If i had bought this domain from Google Domains I could easily setup email accounts associated with that domain, like admin@mydomain.com. For the life of me, I can't figure out how it's done through AWS. I don't want to use my personal account for SES services.

Here's where I'd do that with Google Domains
[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS service most similar to Gmail is called [Amazon WorkMail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/).

The SES service is mainly for sending large amounts of email cheaply. Receiving email on SES is mostly for automating processes that need to respond to an email being received, it's not really for general email account usage.

Comment: Thank you. I've created my email accounts for the specific domain with WorkMail. I thought SES would be a good solution for situations like "forgot your password" emails.

Comment: Yes, SES is a good solution for sending automated emails from your application. It's not great for hosting an actual email account though.